# How can i surcharge a connection configuration from a controller in Lithium?

Tags: php, lithium

I'm building a GooglePlaces API, it is package as an http datasource.

I thought it would be a good idea to ship it with a basic `Places` model & a basic `gplaces` connection so that the datasource could be used out of the box in my app `PlacesController` using :

```
use app\models\Places;
use google\models\Places as GPlaces;

class PlacesController extends \lithium\action\Controller { ... }
```

But i'd like to be able to somehow surcharge the plugin default connection `gplaces` with so API key.

Tried :

```
GPlaces::config(array(
    'key' => '<private_api_key>'
));
```

But it does not affect (as we could expect) the Connection,

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this instance, `GPlaces` is a model, so doing this is only going to assign that key to the model's configuration, which is not what you want.

If you have a connection called `'gplaces'`, it should be configured with that key in `Connections::add()`, then you can tell your model to use that connection like so:

```
GPlaces::config(array(
    'connection' => 'gplaces'
));
```